# momentjs gives Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I'm trying to make my own calendar with momentjs, I have been following the docs on  [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) but it keeps giving me this error: Uncaught Error: `Objects are not valid as a React child`

this is the line that gives the error: `moment([2010, 0, 31]).add(1, 'months');`

I have console.log'ed it and I get an object instead of a string which gives the error, but it's supposed to give a string.

I have made a codeSandBox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-5j3tyg?file=/src/Datovaelger.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your moment date object to a string before display using `format()`.

In your codesandbox, I can't see the error (I guess you removed the problem by not rendering it), but wherever you put this date object in your react render JSX, use `format` before display:

```
moment([2010, 0, 31]).add(1, 'months').format()
```

`format` accepts an argument that describes the output format if you want to manually define this.

This is tangential, but you should be aware `moment` is a bit outdated despite its legacy popularity. See https://momentjs.com/docs/ under "Project Status".

You might consider using something slimmer and more modern whilst you still can.

Comment: Okay thank you for advise, can you recommend any?

Comment: https://moment.github.io/luxon/ is the next version from the folks at moment and https://date-fns.org/ is also popular